# Unable to perform click on kendo Grid

Tags: selenium, automation, kendo-grid

I am trying to click a cell in a kendo grid but not able to achieve. Tried with different options like using Actions, JavaScriptExecutor, etc. Using JS I am able to highlight the particular cell but not able to perform click.

Sample Code

```
HighlightElement(record);  //Method to highlight a web element using JS (working)
driver.FindElement(record).Click();//Trying to click the same element (Not Working)
```

Comment: Can you post some code describing your problem and showing what you already tried?

Comment: Updated with sample code